# Python CSV File Read and Save

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have a problem regarding to save newest seat update to my CSV file.
I want every seat that is booked by user receive changes in CSV file file.
Example : If user book A1 seat, the A1 is CSV file will replaced with X.

My program objective is to read csv file and store it, then make a replacement to it later. Every row have 5 seat. A1-A5 are first row of business class and B1-B5 are second row business class. I expect the program to replace  the seat that is occupied/booked with “X”. 
Example : A1 | X | A3 | A4 | A5 (A2 are not available, it is occupied)

Here is my code :

```
seat =[]
csvfile = open('coba.csv') 
seating = csv.reader(csvfile)
for line in seating:
    seat.append(line)

print("Buy seat ?")
answer_1 = input("Answer : ")
if (answer_1 == "yes"):
    answer_2 = input("Enter preferred seat: ")
    if (answer_2 == "A1"):
        row = 1
        column = 0
        seat[row][column] = "X"
        for line in seat:
            print(' | '.join(line))
        writer = csv.writer(open('coba.csv', 'w'))
        writer.writerows(line)
```

My CSV File :

```
[Business]
A1,A2,A3,A4,A5
B1,B2,B3,B4,B5
[Economy]
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5
D1,D2,D3,D4,D5
E1,E2,E3,E4,E5
```

Error :

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'coba.csv'

Thanks in advance

Comment: may i know why pandas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want this program to do. It's failing because you can't call `len()` on a CSV Reader. What are you trying to append to the CSV file, and what is the condition you want to establish for appending?

Comment: what IS your question? What data do you want to extract? What is with the header line `[Business]`, what are the A1-A5 and B1-B5 are for? What data do you need?

Comment: @Chirag reading in 3 lines of text  - using a full fledged _framework_ like pandas is simply overkill. Not all data has to be processed like a nail, even if you swing a pandas-hammer.

Comment: What is your original objective? Your code is having bugs in 1st line of code. If your intention is to store lines in a data structure then why don't you use list `[]` in place of tuple `()` (it is immutable). Please check my answer. I have just made your code working, there is a different to read and process csv in a better way.

Comment: Thanks for all of your respons, my objective is to read the file and store it, then make a replacement after a seat is occupied

Comment: Every row have 5 seat. A1-A5 is first row for business class, and B1-B5 is second row for business class. If a seat is occupied then the program will replace those labelled seat to “X” , example : A1 | X | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 (A2 seat is occupied, so not available). If you guys have other idea to do this please kindly share the idea. Thanks guys !

Comment: Update your question instead of posting in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have typos. You should have checked `len(line)` instead of `len(seating)` and also using list instead of tuple with your `seat`

```
import csv

def load():
    seat = []
    csvfile = open('x.csv')
    seating = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in seating:
        if len(line) == 5:
            seat.append(line)
    print(seat)

load()
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner by the way, the full csv file have business class and economy class header, so I think to read every line that contain 5 item only

Comment: Thanks for the response dude! I’ll try it, btw the seat is already list, little bit of typo hehe !!

Comment: @CtrlS umm i edited the thread, sorry im new to this platform

Comment: @DeltaTroz What thread did you edit?  You haven't posted any new comments under your question.

Also, you should be editing your question to include the new details you've mentioned in your comments.

Comment: @DeltaTroz I thought you were going to reply to PatrickArtner.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the first 5 lines of column A:

```
from pandas import read_csv

data = read_csv('name.csv')

result = []

for i in range(5):
    result.append(data['A1'][i])
```

Comment: does not work. your df is different from what you think it is, using pandas on 3 rows is overkill in the first place and you are lacking a `:` to make this code work _at all_

Comment: Yes, I forgot. I guess I got the question wrong. The question was very complicated before editing.@PatrickArtner

Answer (score 0):

Populate your seat list with lists of each row

```
seats = []
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvreader:
        line = tuple(row)
        if len(line) == 5:
            seat.append(list(line))
```

Walk through each row in the list and change it to what you need to.

Answer (score -1):

This is just the fix of your code. You can find 50% of fix of your problem at [object of type '_csv.reader' has no len(), csv data not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909314/object-of-type-csv-reader-has-no-len-csv-data-not-recognized).

> There's a better solution for what yout are looking for.

#### How to fix?

- Initialize `seat` as `[]` as we know that tuple `()` is immutable.
- `seating` is an iterator, so convert that into a list if you wish to calculate length.

> coba.py

```
import csv 

def load():
    seat = []
    csvfile = open('coba.csv') 
    seating = csv.reader(csvfile)
    print(type(seating))

    seating = list(seating)
    print(type(seating))

    for line in seating:
        print(seating)
        if len(line[0].split(',')) == 5:
            #print(' | '.join(row))
            seat.append(line)

    print(seat)

load()

"""
<class '_csv.reader'>
<class 'list'>
[['[BUSINESS]'], ['A1,A2,A3,A4,A5'], ['B1,B2,B3,B4,B5']]
[['[BUSINESS]'], ['A1,A2,A3,A4,A5'], ['B1,B2,B3,B4,B5']]
[['[BUSINESS]'], ['A1,A2,A3,A4,A5'], ['B1,B2,B3,B4,B5']]
[['A1,A2,A3,A4,A5'], ['B1,B2,B3,B4,B5']]
"""
```